# Postgresql dynamic function with current table name

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

I have a function (`audit.create_audit_table()`) that accepts an array of table names. It creates a single function `audit.if_modified_func()` and then loops through each table name and creates an audit table and applies a trigger to the main table. The function compiles and is created with no errors. When I run the function

```
select audit.create_audit_table(ARRAY['organization'])
```

I keep getting the following error and I am not sure why because I thought that `TG_TABLE_NAME` is a automatic variable which will give me access to the current table that is executing `audit.if_modified_func()`

ERROR:

```
ERROR:  column "tg_table_name" does not exist
LINE 3:   audit_row audit.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT)||';
                                           ^
```

Here's the function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.create_audit_table(table_names character varying[])
RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
    table_name varchar;
    i int;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE     
        audit_row audit.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT)||';
        include_values boolean;
        log_diffs boolean;
        h_old hstore;
        h_new hstore;
        excluded_cols text[] = ARRAY[]::text[];
    BEGIN
        IF TG_WHEN <> ''AFTER'' THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION ''audit.if_modified_func() may only run as an AFTER trigger'';
        END IF;

        audit_row = ROW(
            nextval(''audit.'|| quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::text) ||'_event_id_seq''), -- event_id
            TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::text,                        -- schema_name
            TG_TABLE_NAME::text,                          -- table_name
            TG_RELID,                                     -- relation OID for much quicker searches
            session_user::text,                           -- session_user_name
            current_timestamp,                            -- action_tstamp_tx
            statement_timestamp(),                        -- action_tstamp_stm
            clock_timestamp(),                            -- action_tstamp_clk
            txid_current(),                               -- transaction ID
            current_setting(''application_name''),          -- client application
            inet_client_addr(),                           -- client_addr
            inet_client_port(),                           -- client_port
            current_query(),                              -- top-level query or queries (if multistatement) from client
            substring(TG_OP,1,1),                         -- action
            NULL, NULL,                                   -- row_data, changed_fields
            ''f''                                           -- statement_only
            );

        IF NOT TG_ARGV[0]::boolean IS DISTINCT FROM ''f''::boolean THEN
            audit_row.client_query = NULL;
        END IF;

        IF TG_ARGV[1] IS NOT NULL THEN
            excluded_cols = TG_ARGV[1]::text[];
        END IF;

        IF (TG_OP = ''UPDATE'' AND TG_LEVEL = ''ROW'') THEN
            audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
            audit_row.changed_fields =  (hstore(NEW.*) - audit_row.row_data) - excluded_cols;
            IF audit_row.changed_fields = hstore('''') THEN
                -- All changed fields are ignored. Skip this update.
                RETURN NULL;
            END IF;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = ''DELETE'' AND TG_LEVEL = ''ROW'') THEN
            audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = ''INSERT'' AND TG_LEVEL = ''ROW'') THEN
            audit_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*) - excluded_cols;
        ELSIF (TG_LEVEL = ''STATEMENT'' AND TG_OP IN (''INSERT'',''UPDATE'',''DELETE'',''TRUNCATE'')) THEN
            audit_row.statement_only = ''t'';
        ELSE
            RAISE EXCEPTION ''[audit.if_modified_func] - Trigger func added as trigger for unhandled case: %%, %%'',TG_OP, TG_LEVEL;
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO audit.'|| quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT) ||' VALUES (audit_row.*);
    RETURN null;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;   
    ALTER FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func()
    OWNER TO postgres;';

    FOR i in 1..array_upper(table_names, 1) LOOP

        EXECUTE format('
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS audit.%1$s;
        CREATE TABLE audit.%1$s (
        event_id bigserial primary key,
        schema_name text not null,
        table_name text not null,
        relid oid not null,
        session_user_name text,
        action_tstamp_tx TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        action_tstamp_stm TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        action_tstamp_clk TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
        transaction_id bigint,
        application_name text,
        client_addr inet,
        client_port integer,
        client_query text,
        action TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (action IN (''I'',''D'',''U'', ''T'')),
        row_data hstore,
        changed_fields hstore,
        statement_only boolean not null
        );

        REVOKE ALL ON audit.%1$s FROM public;

        COMMENT ON TABLE audit.%1$s IS ''History of auditable actions on audited tables, from audit.if_modified_func()'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.event_id IS ''Unique identifier for each auditable event'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.schema_name IS ''Database schema audited table for this event is in'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.table_name IS ''Non-schema-qualified table name of table event occured in'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.relid IS ''Table OID. Changes with drop/create. Get with ''''tablename''''::regclass'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.session_user_name IS ''Login / session user whose statement caused the audited event'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.action_tstamp_tx IS ''Transaction start timestamp for tx in which audited event occurred'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.action_tstamp_stm IS ''Statement start timestamp for tx in which audited event occurred'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.action_tstamp_clk IS ''Wall clock time at which audited event''''s trigger call occurred'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.transaction_id IS ''Identifier of transaction that made the change. May wrap, but unique paired with action_tstamp_tx.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.client_addr IS ''IP address of client that issued query. Null for unix domain socket.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.client_port IS ''Remote peer IP port address of client that issued query. Undefined for unix socket.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.client_query IS ''Top-level query that caused this auditable event. May be more than one statement.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.application_name IS ''Application name set when this audit event occurred. Can be changed in-session by client.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.action IS ''Action type; I = insert, D = delete, U = update, T = truncate'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.row_data IS ''Record value. Null for statement-level trigger. For INSERT this is the new tuple. For DELETE and UPDATE it is the old tuple.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.changed_fields IS ''New values of fields changed by UPDATE. Null except for row-level UPDATE events.'';
        COMMENT ON COLUMN audit.%1$s.statement_only IS ''''''t'''' if audit event is from an FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger, ''''f'''' for FOR EACH ROW'';

        CREATE INDEX %1$s_relid_idx ON audit.%1$s(relid);
        CREATE INDEX %1$s_action_tstamp_tx_stm_idx ON audit.%1$s(action_tstamp_stm);
        CREATE INDEX %1$s_action_idx ON audit.%1$s(action);         
        ', table_names[i]);     

        EXECUTE format('
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS audit_trigger_row ON %1$s;
        CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row
        AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
        ON public.%1$s
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func();', table_names[i]);

        EXECUTE format('
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS audit_trigger_stm ON %1$s;
        CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_stm
        AFTER TRUNCATE
        ON public.%1$s
        FOR EACH STATEMENT
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func();', table_names[i]);

    END LOOP;

RETURN 'SUCCESS';
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
ALTER FUNCTION audit.create_audit_table(character varying[])
OWNER TO postgres;
```

**UPDATE 03/31:**

Ok, so I created the `if_modified_func()` function without the dynamic sql and I declared the audit_row as `audit_row RECORD;` I am not sure about the part of "needing a cast upon inserting the values". I am also not sure if this is the correct way to do the insert

`EXECUTE format($string$INSERT INTO audit.%1$s VALUES (audit_row.*);$string$, TG_TABLE_NAME::text);`

I am now getting this error when I run `select audit.create_audit_table(ARRAY['organization'])`

ERROR:

```
ERROR:  record "audit_row" has no field "row_data"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function audit.if_modified_func() line 42 at assignment
```

Here's the updated function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
        DECLARE     
            audit_row RECORD;            
            include_values boolean;
            log_diffs boolean;
            h_old hstore;
            h_new hstore;
            excluded_cols text[] = ARRAY[]::text[];
        BEGIN
            IF TG_WHEN <> 'AFTER' THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'audit.if_modified_func() may only run as an AFTER trigger';
            END IF;

            audit_row = ROW(
                nextval(format('audit.%1$s_event_id_seq',TG_TABLE_NAME::text)), -- event_id
                TG_TABLE_SCHEMA::text,                        -- schema_name
                TG_TABLE_NAME::text,                          -- table_name
                TG_RELID,                                     -- relation OID for much quicker searches
                session_user::text,                           -- session_user_name
                current_timestamp,                            -- action_tstamp_tx
                statement_timestamp(),                        -- action_tstamp_stm
                clock_timestamp(),                            -- action_tstamp_clk
                txid_current(),                               -- transaction ID
                current_setting('application_name'),          -- client application
                inet_client_addr(),                           -- client_addr
                inet_client_port(),                           -- client_port
                current_query(),                              -- top-level query or queries (if multistatement) from client
                substring(TG_OP,1,1),                         -- action
                NULL, NULL,                                   -- row_data, changed_fields
                'f'                                           -- statement_only
                );

            IF NOT TG_ARGV[0]::boolean IS DISTINCT FROM 'f'::boolean THEN
                audit_row.client_query = NULL;
            END IF;

            IF TG_ARGV[1] IS NOT NULL THEN
                excluded_cols = TG_ARGV[1]::text[];
            END IF;

            IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
                audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
                audit_row.changed_fields =  (hstore(NEW.*) - audit_row.row_data) - excluded_cols;
                IF audit_row.changed_fields = hstore('') THEN
                    -- All changed fields are ignored. Skip this update.
                    RETURN NULL;
                END IF;
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
                audit_row.row_data = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND TG_LEVEL = 'ROW') THEN
                audit_row.row_data = hstore(NEW.*) - excluded_cols;
            ELSIF (TG_LEVEL = 'STATEMENT' AND TG_OP IN ('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','TRUNCATE')) THEN
                audit_row.statement_only = 't';
            ELSE
                RAISE EXCEPTION '[audit.if_modified_func] - Trigger func added as trigger for unhandled case: %, %',TG_OP, TG_LEVEL;
                RETURN NULL;
            END IF;
            EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO audit.%1$s VALUES (audit_row.*)', TG_TABLE_NAME::text);  

        RETURN null;
        END;
        $$
        LANGUAGE plpgsql;   
        ALTER FUNCTION audit.if_modified_func()
        OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: remove `quote_ident`. `quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT)` will apply necessary actions to correcty quote the argument as relation name. So you basically tell `TG_TABLE_NAME` is not variable, but a table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TG_TABLE_NAME` is a special, trigger variable, which is only available inside trigger functions. Your `create_audit_table()` is not a trigger function.

Also, you constantly redefining your real trigger function (`if_modified_func()`), which "invalidates" any earlier created triggers.

Create your trigger function **without** the dynamic SQL magic (dynamic SQL will only need to insert values to these audit tables). Then, you can add your audit logic to a table with:

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_trigger_row
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON public.<your_table_name>
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE <your_audit_trigger_function_name>();
```

You can put this (but only this -- maybe with `drop if exists`) inside a function, to allow attaching this audit logic more easily.

*Notes*:

- Inside the trigger function, you cannot use a `%ROWTYPE` variable (because you don't know the exact table. you only have its name). The solution is simple: just use the `RECORD` type instead (you will need a cast upon inserting the values though).
- Don't use single quotes for such long strings. Use the `$your_keyword$<string_value>$your_keyword$` format instead. With possibly the `format()` function instead of just concatenating values. Your code will be much more readable.

**Edit**: to utilize your `RECORD` variable, you should either:

- Initialize it with a structure. You can do this in your case with f.ex.

  ```
  SELECT nextval('audit.'|| quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME) || '_event_id_seq') AS event_id,
         TG_TABLE_SCHEMA                        AS schema_name,
         TG_TABLE_NAME                          AS table_name,
         TG_RELID                               AS relid,
         session_user                           AS session_user_name,
         current_timestamp                      AS action_tstamp_tx,
         statement_timestamp()                  AS action_tstamp_stm,
         clock_timestamp()                      AS action_tstamp_clk,
         txid_current()                         AS transaction_id,
         current_setting('application_name')    AS application_name,
         inet_client_addr()                     AS client_addr,
         inet_client_port()                     AS client_port,
         current_query()                        AS client_query,
         substring(TG_OP, 1, 1)                 AS action,
         NULL::hstore                           AS row_data,
         NULL::hstore                           AS changed_fields,
         FALSE                                  AS statement_only
  INTO   audit_row;
  ```
- Use the predefined names of the `ROW()` constructor. The first column's name if `f1`, the second's is `f2`, etc.

  ```
  audit_row.f15 = hstore(OLD.*) - excluded_cols;
  ```

After choosing one of the above methods, you should insert the row like:

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO audit.%1$s VALUES (($1::text::audit.%1$s).*)', quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)) USING audit_row;
```

*Note*: even the cast to `text` is required due to the fact that `EXECUTE` cannot know the actual structure of `audit_row`.

http://rextester.com/GUAJ1339

Comment: when you say "Inside the trigger function, you cannot use a %ROWTYPE variable" are you talking about this line `audit_row audit.' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT)||';`

Comment: @iambdot yes. you could use `DECLARE audit_row RECORD` there.

Comment: @lambdot in `EXECUTE`, you can't access variables, which were declated in the PL/pgSQL context. You'll need something like `EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO audit.%1$s VALUES ($1::%1$s.*)', TG_TABLE_NAME::text) USING audit_row` (the cast `::%1$s` is required for PostgreSQL to understand what kind on `RECORD` is `audit_row` exactly).

Comment: thanks for that.i made the change and i still get this error when i do an update to the table `ERROR:  record "audit_row" has no field "row_data"
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function audit.if_modified_func() line 43 at assignment`. it looks like it's failing because of statements like `audit_row.row_data =` OR even `audit_row.changed_fields =`. is there a way to assign fields to the `RECORD` type? if not, should I just create a temp table and insert the data in there and then select the values from it for the main `INSERT`?

Comment: @iambdot I just updated my answer with a working example to insert (and manipulate) the `RECORD` type.

Comment: you are the man..thanks a lot for the knowledge transfer and your patience. I'm a ms sql guy and this is my first attempt at using postgres, and things are a little different..thanks again..i owe you a beer for sure

Answer (score 1):

quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME::TEXT) will apply necessary actions to correcty quote the argument as relation name.

I would recommend using `execute format('statement')` instead of concatinations, eg:

```
t=# do $$ begin raise info '%',format('I am %I, now is %L',current_user,now()); end;$$;
INFO:  I am postgres, now is '2017-03-30 07:33:53.579476+00'
DO
```

Instead of:

```
t=# do $$ begin raise info '%','I am '||quote_ident(current_user)||', now is '||quote_ident(now()::text); end;$$;
INFO:  I am postgres, now is "2017-03-30 07:36:20.495887+00"
DO
```